# Python. Инкремент счетчика в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, for

Как инкрементировать счетчик во время выполнения цикла

```py
for param in range(len(mass)):
   if a==b:
    .
    .
    param+=5
   else:
    .
```

На C# это можно было бы сделать вручную

```cs
for(i=0;i<val;i++)
{
if (a==b)
{
...
i+=5;
}
else ...
}
```

Но в python это не срабатывает, счетчик продолжает идти не смотря ни на что.

Answer (score 3):

Замените цикл `for` на `while`:

```
param=0
while param < len(mass):
    if a==b:
        .
        .
        param+=5
    else:
        .

    param+=1
```